# Unity3d - How to fill plane divided into two with two different color each?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm trying to divide a plane into few section, and to fill each section with different colors.
(Like German flag)

I thought I can use 'for loop' for this work, But i choose wrong tool.

as soon as I apply my shader on to plane, Unity get stuck.

Because I'm new to Shader, I cannot find any way to solve this problem.

I hope you let me know how to divide plane, and fill them with different color.

Here's my Shadercode.

```
'''Shader "Custom/NewSurfaceShader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _UR("Upper Red", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _UG("Upper Green", Range(0,1)) = 1.0
        _UB("Upper Blue", Range(0,1)) = 1.0
        _UA("Upper Alpha", Range(0,1)) = 1.0
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed _UR;
        fixed _UG;
        fixed _UB;
        fixed _UA;
        fixed4 _AlterColor;


        // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
        // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
        // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)

        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
        {
            _AlterColor = fixed4(_UR, _UG, _UB, _UA);
            fixed4 c;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1920; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 2160; j++) {
                    fixed2 hv = fixed2(i / 1920, j / 2160);                 
                    if (hv.x < 0.5) {
                        c = tex2D(_MainTex, (hv))*_AlterColor;
                    }

                    else
                        c = tex2D(_MainTex, (hv)) * _Color;
                }
            }
            o.Emission = c.rgb;
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
'''
```

Comment: And here's Error when unity get stuck.

Failed to present D3D11 swapchain due to device reset/removed. This error can happen if you draw or dispatch very expensive workloads to the GPU, which can cause Windows to detect a GPU Timeout and reset the device.(see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/timeout-detection-and-recovery). If you believe this error is due to built-in Unity functionally, please submit a bug. This is an unrecoverable error and the editor will shut down.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way simpler way to approach this problem.

Try using textures for applying the flag colors to your plane. Simply import an image of the flag that should be shown on the plane and mark it as a texture in the import settings inspector. After that you should be able to drag and drop the texture onto a material named e.g. "flagMaterial". Apply the material to the plane and youre done.

If this doesnt work for some reason you can easily import a color palette into Blender, subdivide it a bunch of times so you have three faces and go to **Shading** and then in **Edit Mode** face select the face you want to paint and assign a color in the **Shading Tab** on the left(default).
Import it into Unity(see workflow for that) and plop it into your scene.

Hope this helps.